# How can I submit a form in .Net Core without leaving the current view and keeping the curent model

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a modal with a form which after I submit I want to update something into the database without leaving or refreshing the current view and without losing my current injected model.

Let me explain this quickly. I have a Profile page that has two buttons. One `I have blocked your car!` and another `Unblock my car!`. When I press one of the buttons a modal will pop up and will ask your for some input for a form which after I submit I want to return on the profile page that I was before pressing the button. I have tried many things and I encountered some problems:

1.After I summited the form the injected model becomes NULL
2.Void actions send me to a blank page
3.After submit the action was not called because I had a breakpoint and also the model got null
4.nothing works

I basically want : when I open the modal and I enter the data, after I submit it a method from the controller should be called to update something in the database without changing the view or refreshing it.. after that I want to return to the profile page that I was before pressing the button
Controller:

```
using AspNetCoreHero.ToastNotification.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnblockMe.Models;
using UnblockMe.Services;

namespace UnblockMe.Controllers
{
    public class ProfileController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ProfileController> _logger;
        private readonly IUserService _userService;
        private readonly INotyfService _notyf;
        private Users _curentUser;
        public ProfileController(ILogger<ProfileController> logger, INotyfService notyf,IUserService userService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _userService = userService;
            _notyf = notyf;

        }

        [Route("Profile/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Index(string id)
        {  

            return View(_userService.GetUserById(id));
        
        }

   
        public void BlockedYouAction(string Contact)
        {
       
        }
    
        public void BlockedMeAction(string Contact)
        {

         
        }
       
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Users
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using UnblockMe.Services
@inject SignInManager<Users> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<Users> UserManager
@inject IUserService _userService
@inject ICarsService _carsService
<p>@Model.FirstName - @Model.LastName</p>
<p>@Model.PhoneNumber</p>
<p>@Model.Email</p>
<div class="container">
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UnblockMe">
            Unblock me!
        </button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="UnblockMe" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Unblock Me!</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="post" id="form" asp-controller="Profile" asp-action="BlockedYouAction">
                            <p>Contact Method:</p>
                            <label for="ContactSMS">SMS</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="Contact" value="SMS" id="ContactSMS" checked />
                            <label for="ContactEmail">Email</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="Contact" value="Email" id="ContactEmail" />

                            <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
                            <select name="mycars" id="mycars">
                                @foreach (var element in _carsService.GetCarsList(_userService.GetLoggedInUser()))
                                {
                                    <option value="@element.LicensePlate">@element.LicensePlate</option>
                                }


                            </select>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="myLink">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#BlockedYou">
            I have blocked you!
        </button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="BlockedYou" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">I have blocked you!</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @Html.Partial("BlockedYou_parital", Model)
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
</div>
<script>
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Currently I am testing the I have blocked you! button so don't look at the other one.
And also I'd like to mention that my profile route is Profile/{user id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to use ajax

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $(document).on("click", "#blockYouBtn", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        blockYou();
    });

function blockYou() {

      var contact= //your code

        $.ajax({
            url: '/profile/BlockedYouAction',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {Contact:contact},
            success: function (result) {
             return true;
            },
            error: function (xhr, exception) {
           //error code
                return false;
            }
        });
};
});

</script>
```

I don't know what do you need after blocking. Now it is doing nothing, but it can for example return a partial view. The model and all another day will not changed.

Comment: After I press the blocking button I want to go in controller, upate the guy car in the database ( field : IsBlockedBY = the license plate of one of my cars) and send him an sms/email and return to it's profile like nothing happened... I want to just open the modal.. submit the form... and after that the modal should dissapear and I should have the same profile page in front of my eyes

Comment: Use ajax to reach a controller action. Inside of the action run the code to change db and return Ok or  BadRequest. All your views with all the data will be untouched.

Comment: You can put some more code after you start if you still have a problem

Comment: Mate, I figured it out :D .. thank you... now i have another problem... after submit the values are not sent to my paramteres of the function... I dont know the syntax.. can you help me out?

Comment: if you have just one string parameter - Contact this code should work fine. But if you have different parameters, pls update your question.